# Pushing View Controller from app delegate Stops the App flow from the Pushed viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have  initialViewController in Storyboard.  then after login I have all ViewControllers in XIB. Now My problem is that I have to show a particular viewcontroller when a push notfication received. I did that in app delegate. But after pushing to the viewcontroller I cant navigate to other viewcontrollers from this viewController. Can I get any help from this or should I post some of the code as well?

Comment: Always provide your code and any console errors you are receiving. Make sure to format them with the tools to make it easier to read

Comment: Click on the viewcontroller class in Storyboard and gotoEditor on the top and click 'Embedin' click navigation controller then try pushing between view controller it will work.

Comment: I solved It my self. Thanks everyone for reply.

Comment: This is how I did it - 
UINavigationController *v_navController = (UINavigationController *)_window.rootViewController;
MyViewController *detailViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
[v_navController.visibleViewController.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES